# "Eventual Consistency" vs "Strong Eventual Consistency" vs "Strong Consistency"?

Tags: distributed-computing

I came across the concept of "Strong Eventual Consistency" .
Is it supposed to be stronger than "Eventual Consistency" but weaker than "Strong Consistency"? Could someone explain the differences among these three concepts with applicable examples?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency#Strong_Eventual_Consistency
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type

Many thanks.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: The text below should give you a rough idea about the differences among Eventual Consistency, Strong Eventual Consistency and Strong Consistency. But they are in some way an over-simplification. So take them with a grain of salt ;)

---

First things first: when we talk about *consistency* we refer to an scenario where different entities (nodes) have their own copy of some data object. Now, conflicts arise because each node can update its own copy (e.g. because there are clients, each one connected to some node, asking them to do so), so if I read the data from different nodes I'll see different values. This is where Eventual Consistency (EC), Strong Eventual Consistency (SEC) and Strong Consistency (SC) come into play.

**Eventual Consistency**
Conflicts can arise, but nodes communicate each other their changes to solve those conflicts, so in time they agree upon the definitive value. Thus, if no more changes are applied to the data for a certain period, then all nodes will agree in the data value (i.e. they will eventually agree) so readers of data will eventually see the same value.

Example: two nodes A and B (*nA* and *nB*) have each one copy of a string, which is update with operations `read()` and `write(string)`. Let's say each one has its own client (*cliA* and *cliB*). Let's say that initially both nodes store the same value "Joe", but at some moment *nA* updates it to "Frank" (calls `write("Frank")`). Then *nA* will tell *nB* that the value has been updated; as both values differ a conflict has arisen but in can be solved using some policy (for example last-write-wins) so *nB* finally updates its record also to "Frank". Before the conflict is resolved *cliA* and *cliB* will see different versions of the data (the `read()` op result will differ), but eventually both will see the same value again.

Keep in mind that if both nodes update their value simultaneously then conflict resolution is still possible but more complicated. This is where SEC shines.

**Strong Eventual Consistency**
This is a special case of EC, that is valid only for certain data types.

Let's assume that the data object shared is a counter, and updates are made by `add(int value)` and `substract(int value)` operations. In this case, *the order in which we apply updates does not matter*! So if both *nA* and *nB* start with a counter value of 0, and if then nA runs `add(10)` and *nB* runs `substract(5)` (simultaneosly), they only need to send the update operation to each other without caring for conflict resolution, eventually it is ensured that they will reach the same value (remember that, in contrast, in the previous example for EC some conflict resolution could be required)!

Unfortunately SEC is only applicable in certain data types and operations that have specific properties (commutativity and others). Such data types are denoted **Conflict-free Replicated Data Type (CRDT)** .

**Strong consistency**
Quite different to the other two. Here it is a requirement that upon update operations all nodes agree on the new value before making the new value visible to clients. That way updates are visible to all clients 'at the same time', so they will read the same value at all times. Now this introduces the requirement for some blocking in update operations. Both in EC and SEC an update operation was over as soon as the local copy was updated (then the operation was broadcasted to the other nodes). Here a client update does not return until all nodes have agreed upon the data value, and while this is done all accesses to any copy of that data are 'locked' (so other clients reads are blocked). In our example for EC, if *cliA* runs `write("Frank")`, *cliA* will be blocked until the update is agreed by both *nA* and *nB*, and then it will made visible for both *cliA* and *cliB* at the same time, i.e. the `read()` operation should return the same value from then on.

Comment: To clarify, strong consistency only requires that all nodes agree on the current value. It's not a requirement that the nodes block reads while a write occurs, they can instead cause the write to be delayed. Basically, the write will be in a pending state, until a time all nodes can agree to use the new value consistently.

Comment: Do i understand correctly, that if a replica node is down, the strong consistency is unachievable - by definition? In other words a distributed system cannot guarantee fault tolerance and strong consistency at the same time?

Comment: Hi Alexey. Even if a node is down, if the remaining nodes can still reach an agreement, then it is still considered strong consistency. Unfortunately if crashes are possible (i.e. the real world) then consistency is tricky. I recommend to take a look to these slides:
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos461/docs/lec24-strong.pdf

Last slide shows what is actually possible in distributed systems. You can see that Paxos alg allows for strong consistency + partition tolerance. It can handle up to F crashed nodes, as long as F+1 nodes are still up.

Comment: @LuisRodero-Merino So strong consistency is similar to MESI cache coherence protocol. In order to write a new value, I need to get ACK messages from all peers to allow me to perform the write. Only when all messages are received, I am allowed to write the data.
Right?

Comment: I don't know MESI so I don't know if it is comparable :( ... in any case, in Paxos the leader 'only' needs the majority of participants to accept the value proposed. Then it sends that new value to all participants.

Comment: @LuisRodero-Merino in your answer, does `strong consistency` implies [**linearizability**](https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/linearizable)? Thanks .

Comment: On SEC and EC (Strong Eventual Consistency and Eventual Consistency), from Wikipedia, "Whereas eventual consistency is only a liveness guarantee (updates will be observed eventually), strong eventual consistency (SEC) adds the safety guarantee that any two nodes that have received the same (unordered) set of updates will be in the same state"

Comment: Also, about Eventual Consistency (EC), " if no new updates are made to a given data item, eventually all accesses to that item will return the last updated value."  This is much more succinct and clear to me than the accepted answer.